# XML DOM SetProxy

Tags: asp-classic, xmldom

I am looking at use the XML SetProxy as I am having DNS issue, so I would like to use the IP to connect.

What the easiest way to do this?

I've tried ..

```
.setProxy 2, "XX.XX.XX.XX", ""
```

But it doesn't seem to work, can anyone point me in the right redirection?

Comment: This is against a `ServerXMLHTTP` instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
oXMLHTTP.setProxy 2, "http=myProxyServer:80", ""
```